# How to get the style attributes from html in C#?

Tags: c#

I am not able to get the complete style attributes in C# for:

```
<div style="width: 1280px; height: 1035px; display: none;" id="screen"></div>
```

I tried using `GetAttribute("style")`, but it only gives me the width and height while I need the display. Does anyone know how to get all the attributes?

Comment: What DOM API are you using? You haven't said.

Comment: If display is not explicitly defined it will not return it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use C# to get the style tag? I.e. - you're attempting some logic in a postback.  Couldn't this be better handled using jQuery?

Comment: Is there any way I can get the display attribute, I cannot change the code because I need the attribute for Selenium Automation

Comment: I am using C# as the scripting language in Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/200422/how-to-get-attribute-from-html-div-tag-in-C-Sharp.aspx

Otherwise, why do you want to get values of attributes with C#. HTML is client-side and C# is server-side. I advise you to use JQuery framework and use this line to get the value of the 'style' attribute:

```
 $("#screen").attr("style")
```

You can also get the value with the traditional javascript without framework but it's less user-friendly.